# How can i remove plist file from LaunchDaemons when i drag my application to trash

Tags: macos, uninstallation, recycle-bin

I have a mac application which stores a plist file in Lauchdaemons (which starts the local server).
Also there is a chrome extension file in */Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions* directory which needs to be removed.

When i simply drag the application from /Applications to trash, it does not event stop the server since plist file in LauchDaemons is not deleted. Also the extension is not removed.

Is there any way to run some script when the user drags the app to trash?